# Call two models in a controller using Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I am trying to do is to display two models in my view with help of the controller in Code Igniter and PHP. The first model was displayed successfully in my view, so please don't pay attention to it, but I have difficulties with the second. I cannot display it in my view.

Second model contains a JSON plugin and HTML parsing. I have tested it in a Code Igniter Controller, which works fine with no errors and gives the output I want to have - a HTML table, but now I want it to use it as a model and call it in another controller:

```
class Telephonelist_model extends CI_Model{
    public function telephoneNum(){
        //authentication
        $username = '****';
        $password = '****';
        $sc = new ServerClient();
        $login = "******";
        $content = $sc->getContent($login,array(),false);   


        $host = "*******";
        $content = $sc->getContent($host);
        $content = json_decode($content);

        //Prepair for parsing, select the text part
        foreach($content->parse->text as $myHtml);
        /**
         * Parsing
         */
        //create new dom object
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        //load html source
        $html = $dom->loadHTML($myHtml);

        //discard white space
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

        //the table by its tag name
        $table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

        //get all rows from the table
            $rows = $table->item(2)->getElementsByTagName('tr');
            $tab = '<table>';
            foreach ($rows as $row)
            {
                // get each column by tag name
                $head = $row->getElementsByTagName('th');
                // echo the values
                if(isset($head->item(0)->nodeValue)){
                //echo '<th>';
                    $tab = '<tr><th>'.$tab.$head->item(0)->nodeValue.' </th>';
                }
                if(isset($head->item(1)->nodeValue)){
                //echo '<th>';
                $tab = '<th>'.$tab.$head->item(1)->nodeValue.' </th>';
                }

                if(isset($head->item(2)->nodeValue)){
                $tab = '<th>'.$tab.$head->item(2)->nodeValue.'<br /></th></tr>';
                }
                $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
                // echo the values
                if(isset($cols->item(0)->nodeValue)){
                $tab ='<tr><td>'.$tab.$cols->item(0)->nodeValue.' </td>';
                }

                if(isset($cols->item(1)->nodeValue)){
                $tab = '<td>'.$tab.$cols->item(1)->nodeValue.' </td>';
            }

                if(isset($cols->item(2)->nodeValue)){
                $tab = '<td>'.$tab.$cols->item(2)->nodeValue.' <br /></td></tr></table>';
                }
            }
            return $tab;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Page extends CI_Controller{

    /**
     * Startmethode des Controllers
     * @param string $param1
     * @param string $param2
     */
    public function index($param1=null,$param2=null){
        $this->myCal($param1,$param2);
    }   

    protected function myCal($year=null, $month=null){
        $year = Util_helper::getParamAsInt($year);
        $month = Util_helper::getParamAsInt($month);

        $this->load->model('Mycal_model');
        $data['calendar'] = $this->Mycal_model->generate($year,$month);


        //Get the telephonenumber list
        $this->load->model('Telephonelist_model');
        $data['tab'] = $this->Telephonelist_model->telephoneNum();

        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
```

My view works fine until I include line: $data['tab'] = $this->Telephonelist_model->telephoneNum(); After that nothing is displayed in my view,even the calender.

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="main"> 
       <div class = "table">

        <p>Telefonliste</p>
        <?php echo $tab;?>

    </div>

    <div class = "calender">

        <?php echo $calendar; ?>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you vardump($data['tab']) before loading the view, just to check what data is coming after callin the function

Comment: maybe it's a syntax error somewhere. Try showing the errors by doing this in root's index.php line 35:
  case 'development':
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: @Deepanshu, I have done it, but nothing comes as an output. I think that the problem is in the line : $data['tab'] = $this->Telephonelist_model->telephoneNum(); Because I put a simple echo "1"; before this line and 1 comes as an output.

Comment: @thedjaney , thank you, now I know the problem:Fatal error: Class 'ServerClient' not found. This ServerClient is needed for the JSON plugin and somehow it cannot be found.

Comment: means your function telephoneNum is not executing

Comment: Yes, I guess, because my ServerClient doesn't work again...

Comment: No problem. Generally, if there are no error messages, you make them show. If they still don't show, walk through the whole code by placing die('works'); in all lines 1 step at a time until the word "works" shows. That way you will get to the specific line of code where the problem is.

Comment: @thedjaney, there are far more useful than an empty page :)thanks again!

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try showing the errors by doing this in root's index.php line 35:

```
case 'development':
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am only sorry that I cannot vote for your comments but my reputation is not enough high to do it.

Comment: I think you can accept this answer by clicking the "check" icon?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading both models on the beginning. I have this issue frecuently and always need to do this.

So:

```
protected function myCal($year=null, $month=null){
    $this->load->model('Mycal_model');
    $this->load->model('Telephonelist_model');
    //the rest of your code
```

Also, check this line:
foreach($content->parse->text as $myHtml);

maybe it's stopping the execution of the script? i have never seen a foreach like that.

Comment: Thank you, @Carlos Goce! But it hasn't help. I still have nothing displayed in my view.

Comment: Check if your telephoneNum() is working. Put a return 'test'; on top of the method or something like that.

Comment: Definitely, there is a problem with my JSON plugin. My $content is empty, therefore $myHtml too.